# Word 2016 How to fix text position?

Tags: microsoft-word

How to fix text position in word 2016?
Adding new text in word results in pushing down the content of everything below as one expects. This creates usually problems with the formatting.

What I would like is to have fixed sections that are not affected by changes above.

Here is the problem.

Chapter 1

Bla bla

____________________________________________________end of previous 10
____________________________________________________new page        11

Chapter 2

Oops I forgot to add something Here is the problem.

Chapter 1

Bla bla

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

___________________________________________________end of previouspage 10
____________________________________________________new page           11

(shifted position of chapter all the stuff below and chapter 2 because of the added text )

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

Chapter 2 (shifted formatting)

**Ideal would be

Chapter 1

Bla bla

|new stuff added

____________________________________________________end of previous    10
____________________________________________________beginning of page  11
automatically creates new page not to mess the 
content below

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

|new stuff added

____________________________________________________end of page        11

____________________________________________________page               12

Chapter 2 fixed position at top of page**

Comment: So you basically want each chapter to start with a page break?

Comment: Your self-answer indicates that you solved the problem.  Consider accepting an answer to signify that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going to the next page by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> multiple times, the better approach is to use **page break** to avoid what you described in your question. When you're done writing a page and want to start a next page, press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> . Now if you edit your previous pages, it would not mess up!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone experience same difficulty. This worked actually.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-word/how-to-fix-text-position-in-word-2016/284a4f34-65af-4582-9265-6ed1a8d1ee18?tm=1464500961091

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: That link is to a forum post with a lot of suggestions.  Which one is what actually worked for you?